Not getting the selected rows of jQuery Datatable that uses Ajax call
I am working on a ASP.Net Core MVC C# app and in my single View, I am using 2 jQuery Datatables. I am using ajax call to load the datatable. I am getting below error in my console. There is no error thrown while running the app. I am able to select one or more rows in the datatables by clicking on the rows of datatables. But I am not able to get the selected rows in the code. I am using below codes :
 $(document).ready(function () {

        var excludeTable = LoadTableExclude();
        // Row selection on exclude table row click
        $('#excludeTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        });

        var includeTable = LoadTableInclude();
        // Row selection on include table row click
        $('#includeTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        });

But I am not able to get the selected rows in the button click.
       $('#btnRight').click(function () {
            var selectedRows = excludeTable.rows({ selected: true }).data().toArray();
            var ids = selectedRows.map(row => row.siteCode); //siteCode is an ID value
            
            if (ids.length === 0) {
                alert("Please select rows to move.");
                return;
            }

I always get "Please select rows to move." message when clicking on the btnRight button after selecting any row in the exclude table.
The error in the console is shown below : What is the problem ? How to solve ?


Would be great to include the complete configuration for DataTable with sample data.

I'm afraid you'd better to share a minimal sample for reproducing your issue so that we could help.

Here's my test sample based on your codes. And trying my codes, you will see that selectedRows.length is the total row length while selectedRows2.length is the selected row length. So that if you want your codes to work well, you need to use excludeTable.rows('.selected').data().
There's another option that you can comment $('#table1 tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {}) and uncomment the code snippets in my sample, then you will use the row-selection feature provided by the plugin, then both excludeTable.rows({ selected: true }).data() and excludeTable.rows('.selected').data() will have the same result.
Related link: multi-row-selection and single-row-seletion
<div class="datagrid" id="datagrid1">
    <table id="table1" class="display table-bordered"
           style="width:100%">
    </table>
</div>

<div>
    <button id="btnRight">get selected row</button>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    @* <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script> *@

    <script>
        var excludeTable;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            excludeTable =  $('#table1').DataTable({
                // select: {
                //     style: 'single'//multi
                // },
                ajax: {
                    "url": "/table/LoadStuds",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "dataSrc": function (myJson) {
                        console.info(myJson)
                        return myJson;
                    }
                },
                columns: [
                    { data: 'studID', title: 'StudID', autoWidth: true },
                    { data: 'studCode', title: 'Stud Code', autoWidth: true },
                    { data: 'classNo', title: 'Class No', autoWidth: true },
                    { data: 'teacher', title: 'Teachere', autoWidth: true },
                    { data: 'remarks', title: 'Remarks', autoWidth: true },
                ]
            });

            $('#table1 tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                console.info($(this));
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');
            });
        });

        $('#btnRight').click(function () {
            var selectedRows = excludeTable.rows({ selected: true }).data();
            var selectedRows2 = excludeTable.rows('.selected').data();
            alert(selectedRows.length);
            console.log(selectedRows[0]);
            alert(selectedRows2.length);
            console.log(selectedRows2[0]);
        });
    </script>
}

My test result.


HI @Tiny Wang thanks for your answer. But it didnt help me. Because I am getting the correct result from 'alert($('#excludeTable tbody tr.selected').length + ' row(s) selected');'. But when it comes to get the selected row using the code - var selectedRows = excludeTable.rows({ selected: true }).data() - i am getting blank result. That is the problem.

I am selecting the rows using the code - $('#excludeTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
$(this).toggleClass('selected');
}); - And I am able to select the rows and rows are getting highlighted. But I am not able to get the selected rows in - var selectedRows = excludeTable.rows({ selected: true }).data() and var ids = selectedRows.map(row => row.siteCode);

Hi @KitKat, could you please try var selectedRows = excludeTable.rows('.selected').data(); and see whether you still get the blank result?

Hi @Tiny Wang. I am getting [Object Object]. After that it says 'please select rows to move'. var selectedRows = excludeTable.rows('.selected').data();
alert(selectedRows);
var ids = selectedRows.map(row => row.siteCode);
            if (ids.length === 0) {
                alert("Please select rows to move.");
                return;
            }


Could you pls try console.info(selectedRows[0]); to see the detailed information? Let's make sure we already get the correct data we wanna to gather first. Then based on your code snippet, if you want to get the ids, you should use var selectedRows = excludeTable.rows('.selected').data().toArray(); console.info(selectedRows[0]); var ids = selectedRows.map(row => row.siteCode);

I checked your profile and I found that you had several questions based on similar codes, but looks a little complex... I noticed that you seemed to use select: {style: 'multi'} configuration in datatable loading, then you have to add <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script> libaray. Then you can comment $('#includeTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {$(this).toggleClass('selected');});. Could you pls also try it?

console.info(selectedRows[0]); gives "undefined" on both cases. I included that library and commented the code as you said. But I could not select any rows from the datatable. Please help.

Assuming you are using codes in this question, I say, the question, but not the answer. Then you are using select: {style: 'multi'} in that case, then pls add <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script> and pls keep commenting $('#table1 tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {}). I trust we should be able to click to select the rows. I already test it in my side and if it doesn't work, pls add @section Scripts{ to surround the script just like what I shared in my post.

Hi @Tiny Wang Yes that question i asked and related to this issue.

We need to make sure we could select multiple rows via dataTables.select.min.js plugin, then based on my test, when we could select multiple rows through this plugin, using var selectedRows = excludeTable.rows('.selected').data(); should be able to get the rows, and we might add console.info(selectedRows[0]); to see whether we are getting the correct row data. Then using your toArray() and map method to get the ids. There are 3 steps:1 select rows 2 get the selected row data 3 get your ids . Pls kindly let me know which step traps you after following my suggestions.

When I used the library under @section Scripts and commented that code...yes i am able to select the rows as you said. Thanks. But when I checked the console.info(selectedRows[0]) - it still shows "undefined".

But when I used this line - alert($('#excludeTable tbody tr.selected').length + ' row(s) selected'); - it shows the correct number of selected row. Other methods are failed.

okay that means we are trapped at step 2, firstly, I hope you could clean your project and  empty the browser cache and reload the website. Then let's assume that we have codes like this var selectedRows = excludeTable.rows({ selected: true }).data();            var selectedRows2 = excludeTable.rows('.selected').data();             alert(selectedRows.length);            console.log(selectedRows[0]);alert(selectedRows2.length);console.log(selectedRows2[0]); . Then could you pls let me know the results of the console and alert?

I had a test in my side again with your codes and it worked. https://i.sstatic.net/bZTkgAkU.png   Based on my test, I'm afraid you misconfigured some places beause your data and fields are different than mine.
